# Firebase not filtering query on child value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase Database record has the following properties:

```
timestamp: "1603347996"
primaryKey: "EFh4ShrplQ1603347996"
is_default: "0"
message: "Test"
picture: ""
user_id: "135671325"
```

I'm trying to:

- sort everything in the path by `timestamp`
- start with the record that has  a `primaryKey` value equal to `EFh4ShrplQ1603347996`
- take the next 3 records

The code I'm trying to do that with is:

```
Database.database().reference(withPath: "/chats/123")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
    .queryStarting(atValue: "EFh4ShrplQ1603347996", childKey: "primaryKey")
    .queryLimited(toFirst: 3)
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
        snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
    }
```

However, what's printed is: `Snap (484208593) <null>`

If I drop the `queryStarting(atValue:childKey:)` call, I get the first 3 records from that path, as expected.

The record with `EFh4ShrplQ1603347996` as the `primaryKey` is the 3rd record, when the path is sorted by `timestamp` and there are 10 other records sequentially after that record, which I would expect to be matched by my desired query.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how the `queryStarting(atValue:, childKey)` method works. The first parameter to that call is the **value** of the property that you ordered on, so in your case a `timestamp`. The second parameter is the **key** of the node to start at, in case the `timestamp` value is ambiguous (so there are more nodes with the same `timestamp` value).

So the proper call is:

```
Database.database().reference(withPath: "/chats/123")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
    .queryStarting(atValue: "1603347996", childKey: "theKeyOfTheNode")
```